# How can I figure out what the minimum MaxMem value could be without causing issues. MSSQL 2017 Enterprise CU18

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, memory

I am running several 2017 CU18 instances in failover clusters with "standby" instances for planned growth. I want to configure those standby instances with the least amount of RAM (lowest possible MaxMem). MS Documentation states that the minimum setting is 128GB, but if I go anywhere near that the instance crashes. The lowest stable amount seems to vary between instances on identical hardware/software. I'm hoping there is some sort of formula that can be determined using DMVs i.e. sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors.

Comment: Can you share the MS Documentation? I think you're confusing the terms. 128 GB  should not be the minimum setting, but the max for Standard Edition.
The minimum memory for instance should be 1GB.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 however you should increase the memory for the SQL Server instances to have a good performance. How much? That will depend on your applictions.

Comment: Did you set _maximum_ to 128 _MB_? Can you share the actual error message that causes the instance to crash?

Answer (score 1):

> MS Documentation states that the minimum setting is 128GB,

No I guess you misread somewhere, the minimum amount of RAM required for non express edition is 1 GB but that value is absurd if you ask me. IMHO it should be 4 GB. Here is [hardware and software requirement for SQl Server 2016/2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Ideally the RAM should be same on both the nodes or all the nodes of WSFC or SQL FCI.

I would also like you to describe your problem in details.